# How to sync two folders on my machine, in one directional syncing?

Tags: filesystem, files, directory, sync

I have a set-up in which I create a certain file, and subsequently move it into a storage area for that type of file (folder A). There is another folder on my machine where I must also copy the file to (folder B).

Is there any way to make a set-up in which:

- a file, created in folder A, gets automatically copied to Folder B, if it doesn't exist in folder B?
- I will be notified if new file(s) appear in Folder B, which are not in folder A?

Both folders are on the same file system.

It doesn't have to be fully automatic; I would prefer to run some command in terminal to check for new files in need to be copied to Folder B, copy them and notify me which files have been copied. Also if there are any files in Folder B that are not in Folder A.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, with GNOME Shell, and GNOME 3.16.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to periodically run a small script, say every five minutes, or does it have to be instantaneous? A shell script would do an `rsync` from Folder A to Folder B, then run a `ls` on both folders and `diff` that, resulting in a `zenity` message for every file found in Folder B but not in Folder A. EDIT you DO want a shell script.

Comment: @Jos: I have updated my question.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you need this? What is the final goal? Why not just use symbolic links for FolderA -> FolderB

Comment: Seems a nice task for unison: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (python) option, offering a bit of a "fancy" report:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Newly copied from /home/jacob/map 1 to /home/jacob/map 2:
- Naamloos document
- pscript_2.py
- test123
- monkey_out.txt
----------------------------------------------------------
Unique files in /home/jacob/map 2:
- file_in_targetfolder
----------------------------------------------------------
```

It does what you describe:

- it copies files from folder A to B if they do not (yet) exist in B
- reports files in B, which are not in A

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os
import shutil

folder_1 = sys.argv[1]; folder_2 = sys.argv[2]
files_1 = os.listdir(folder_1); files_2 = os.listdir(folder_2)
# make the length (n) of separating line "smart"
s = "\nNewly copied from "+folder_1+" to "+folder_2+':'; n = len(s)
print("\n"+n*"-"+s)
for f in files_1:
    f1 = folder_1+"/"+f
    if all([os.path.isfile(f1), not f in files_2]):
        shutil.copyfile(f1, folder_2+"/"+f)
        print("-",f)
print(n*"-"+"\nUnique files in "+folder_2+":")
for f in files_2:
    f2 = folder_2+"/"+f
    if all([os.path.isfile(f2), not f in files_1]):
        print("-",f)
print(n*"-")
```

#### How to set up

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `sync_report.py`
2. Test- run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/sync_report.py <folder_a> <folder_b>
   ```

   If the directories contain spaces, put them between single quotes.
3. If all works fine, use it as above, or:

   - make the script executable
   - add the following command to a shortcut key:

     ```
     gnome-terminal -e "'/path/to/sync_report.py' '/path/to/folder_a' '/path/to/folder_b'"
     ```

     Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command.

   Then, when the key combination is pressed:

   [image]

   Don't let the background distract you, my terminal is semi-transparent. :)

Alternatively, as mentioned by @ParanoidPanda (thanks for mentioning), add it to your `~/.bashrc` file. Create an alias which calls the script:

```
alias <nameofalias>='python3 /path/to/sync_report.py <folder_a> <folder_b>'
```

Comment: @ParanoidPanda nice edit, how could I forget!

Answer (score 4):

*Warning*: this is for bidirectional syncing, but given that you are ok in doing things manually... I do not know if there is an option for unidirectional behavior in `unison` --- if anyone knows please feel free to edit this answer.

Install unison:

```
 sudo apt-get install unison unison-gtk
```

Create this file in the directory `$HOME/.unison`, call it `test.prf` (or whatever)

```
label = sync folders A and B
root = /home/romano/tmp/folderA
root = /home/romano/tmp/folderB
```

Run `unison` from the dash, choose your profile above and do a first synchronization. You'll have a graphic interface to choose what to copy and where.

After that, do changes and when you want to keep in sync, use unison again. It will let you decide what to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going. `zenity` has many more applications beyond the scope of your question; customize this as you like.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 ./FolderA | sort > FolderA.txt
ls -1 ./FolderB | sort > FolderB.txt
FILESTOCOPY=$(diff FolderA.txt FolderB.txt | grep \< | awk '{print $2;}' | zenity --list --title="Select files to be copied" --co$
echo $FILESTOCOPY
NEWFILES=$(diff FolderA.txt FolderB.txt | grep \> | awk '{print $2;}' | zenity --list --title="New files in Folder B" --column="f$
echo $NEWFILES
```

Some explanation:

The `ls -1` commands list the file names one line at a time, but only the names, no other information. This script will therefore not notice when a file in one folder is newer than one in the other folder with the same name.

Grepping for "<" will give us files in Folder A but not in Folder B, and vice versa for ">".
You could use the variables created by `zenity` to build a copy command, or something else.

Comment: And I am assuming that `FolderA.txt` and `FolderB.txt` can be stored anywhere you like? That is if you input the file path into the script.

Comment: Yes, simply enter the full path names for FolderA and FolderB as required, and find somewhere sensible to store the temporary files `FolderA.txt` and `FolderB.txt` as well.

Comment: So where does it currently assume `FolderA` and `B` are? If you imagine that they are in my home directory in another folder called `Folders`, what would the `ls -1` lines look like?

Comment: I would recommend `ls -1 ~/Folders/FolderA | sort > ~/Folders/FolderA.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/Fitus/Zaloha.sh. It a shell script that runs out of the box. It is interactive, so you will see and confirm what it is going to do.