# Sync specific folder between two Ubuntu machines when connected to the same LAN

Tags: networking, sync, file-sharing, shared-folders

I have two Ubuntu machines, a laptop and a desktop.
What I wish to do is, to create a folder in both machines at paths 'path1' and 'path2'.
I want to set up sync between the two folders whenever they are connected to the same local area network (Desktop through Ethernet and Laptop through WLAN). So for example, if I create a file path1/x, it will also appear in path2 as path2/x.

Is there a way I can get this done? [It's ok if deletion sync doesn't work and I have to manually delete a file from both directories simultaneously]

Comment: May be this page shows already your answer?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/727304/automatically-do-a-two-way-sync-of-two-directories

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Answering my own question as I found a nice way to do this]

Use `unison` tool developed by Benjamin Pierce at U Penn.

Let us assume you have two directories,

`/home/user/Documents/dirA/` and `/home/user/Documents/dirB/`

To synchronize these two, you may use:

~$`unison -ui text /home/user/Documents/dirA/ /home/user/Documents/dirB/`

In output, `unison` will display each and every directory and file that is *different* in the two directories you have asked to sync. It will recommend to additively synchronize (replicate missing file in both locations) on the initial run, then create and maintain a synchronization tree on your machine, and on subsequent runs it will implement true synchronization (i.e., if you delete a file from `.../dirA`, it will get deleted from `.../dirB` as well. You can also compare each and every change and optionally choose to *forward* or *reverse* synchronize between the two directories.

Optionally, to launch graphical interface, simply remove the `-ui text` option from your command, although I find the `cli` simpler and faster to use.

More on this: [Unison documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison).

Answer (score -2):

Check out this tutorial on [how to sync folders using rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps/).

*Cheers*

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: For the community to be more effective, it is necessary to provide more detail in the answers, a link is not enough, in which case it is not an answer but rather a comment.